# setting Style property of a WebControl From Code Behind

Tags: asp.net, styles, code-behind, web-deployment

recently I *found* in one of my older projects (`asp.net 4.0`)
that I've been using this code

to set `display` Style-property To `none`

```
DDL_ChosenEmpl.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");
```

lately I was using

```
DDL_ChosenEmpl.Style.Add("display", "none");
```

i would like to know

1. in any case such as  - property already exist whether it's with different value or not ,        will any of them should be avoided ?
2. what are the main differences between both methods ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both does the same functionality as you have done. The thing is, in "Attributes" collection, you have a control's other attributes like "click", "dblclick", etc. You can use either way. I believe Microsoft has given the later part for user's convinience to make coding easy.

Comment: thanks for your Quick reply, hopfully You Are Right as i thought too though was not sure about it.